# Rmarkdown with runtime shiny can't plot rCharts plots

Tags: plot, shiny, nvd3.js, r-markdown, rcharts

I have created a Rmarkdown document with shiny runtime. The reason is that depending on some selections, the data is fetched from a database and the output (tables and plots) are updated accordingly to the new selections. For the plots I was using ggplot2 and this is working fine, but I wanted to introduce more interaction using rCharts, and here is where I'm stuck, having tried a variety of combinations using renderPlot(), renderChart() and renderChart2() returning the rCharts object p, using p$show() or p$print() with different parameters, none of the options working for me. 
These are code samples I'm using.
Header:

```
---
title: "my title"
runtime: shiny
output:
  html_document
ext_widgets: {rCharts: [libraries/nvd3]}
---
```

Here is the plotting code

````
```{r, echo=FALSE, comment = NA, results = "asis", comment = NA, tidy = F}
renderPlot({
  data.dt <- data.table(analysisData())
  aggdata2 <- as.data.frame(data.dt[, lapply(.SD, sum), by = date])
  aggdata2 <- aggdata2[with(aggdata2,order(date)),]
  p <- nPlot(y ~ date, data = aggdata2, type = "lineChart", width = 600)
  p$xAxis(
      tickFormat =   "#!
      function(d) {return d3.time.format('%Y-%m-%d')(new Date(d*1000*3600*24));}
      !#"
    )
  #p$print()
  #p$show('iframesrc', cdn =TRUE, include_assets=TRUE)
  return(p)
})
```
````

Which is indeed the best solution I have found so far: it is opening a new window with the chart that I want to create. However, it leaves a blank space in the markdown html where I want the chart to be.

For the analysisData() function here is a simplified code

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
analysisData <- reactive({
  variable1 = input$variable1
  variable2 = input$variable2


  tables = "sqlTable"
  drv <- dbDriver("PostgreSQL")
  dbname <- "dbname"; dbuser <- "dbuser"; 
  dbport = dbport
  dbhost <- "dbhost.com";
  con <- dbConnect(drv, host=dbhost, port = dbport, dbname=dbname, user=dbuser)

  selectStatement = "select * from %s where variable1=%s and variable2=%s"
  query = sprintf(selectStatement, tables, variable1, variable2)

  dataset <- dbGetQuery(con,query)
  lapply(dbListConnections(drv),dbDisconnect)
  dbUnloadDriver(drv)
  dataset$date <- as.Date(dataset$date)
  dataset
})
```
````

Do you have any suggestions on how can I solve the problem? Any hint is appreciated.

Comment: I also struggled quite a bit with nvd3 rCharts plots in Rmarkdown. One solution that worked was saving the plot as a standalone html, then calling it in an iframe tag. See [this](https://gist.github.com/ramnathv/8084330). As an alternative, I recommend [Plotly](https://plot.ly/r/) for interactivity.